# Retrieve Artifactory BuildInfo timestamp properties

Tags: artifactory

I publish the BuildInfo to Artifactory using:

```
    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

    /* Set artifact properties */
    buildInfo.env.capture = true
    buildInfo.env.collect()

    // Publish the build to Artifactory
    server.upload spec: uploadSpec, buildInfo: buildInfo
```

I would like to retrieve the four property assigned to artifacts in Artifactory. I see properties being set such as *build.name*, *build.number*, *build.timestamp*, and *vcs.revision*

I can get the build number and name using:

```
    def buildName = buildInfo.name
    def buildNumber = buildInfo.number
```

How would I go about to retrieve the timestamp and vcs.number from the BuildInfo so that I can do a REST call and post the same four properties to a folder I create in Artifactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Jenkins Build Timestamp Plugin and used this UTC pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

In my groovy file, I added these two commands:

`time=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", BUILD_TIMESTAMP)
epoch_milis = time.getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp in buildinfo is called [started](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/a7c7dc49a417f715d307ef8b1bd28b1c62068143/build-info-api/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/api/builder/BuildInfoBuilder.java#L93), as for `vcs.number` I assume you mean [revision](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info/blob/a7c7dc49a417f715d307ef8b1bd28b1c62068143/build-info-api/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/api/builder/BuildInfoBuilder.java#L106)?

Comment: How do I retrieve that value? I tried buildInfo.started but it says “No such property: started for class: ....buildInfo.BuildInfo